# show data in scrollable data in 9700

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I want to show data in list which is scroll able. I get web service response and I get one BlackBerry support form to scroll data. But I want to implement this after web service call.

For scrolling I used this:

```
<div class="scroll-pane" id="mainBodyDiv">
<ul x-blackberry-focusable="true">
<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="1" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> a</li>
<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="2" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> b</li>
<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="3" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> c</li>
<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="4" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> d</li>
<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="5" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> d</li>
<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="6" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> e</li>
<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="7" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> f</li>
<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="8" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> g</li>
<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="9" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> g</li>


<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="11" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> a</li>
<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="12" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> b</li>
<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="13" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> c</li>
<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="14" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> d</li>
<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="15" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> d</li>
<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="16" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> e</li>
<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="17" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> f</li>
<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="18" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> g</li>
<li x-blackberry-focusable="true" id="19" x-blackberry-onUp="scroll()" x-blackberry-onDown="scroll()"> g</li>
</ul>
```

But what if I want to print 10 number in list after web service call(as a example).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly.  Are you asking whether a scrollable list is possible in webworks?  If so, yes it is possible.  Refer to the following sample applications and most of them have list in them.

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/sampleapps

Thanks

Naveen M